# ASP.Net 5 connect to open database

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am exploring the new ASP.Net 5 functionality with VS 2015. I like the idea of my web app being OS agnostic, so I want to stick to using the aspnetcore50 framework. Since I want my code to be portable to Linux eventually, I want to use an open database such as MySql or PostgreSQL. It doesn't look like any of the Nuget packages (such as Npgsql) are compatible since they all rely on System.Data and for the coreclr, only System.Data.Common is available.

How does Microsoft plan on supporting linux if the only database drivers available are for Sql Server? Should I just target aspnet50 framework and trust that eventually open database drivers will become available that will support aspnetcore50?

Comment: First, VS 2015 isn't even announced and none of the features are finalized yet. Secondly, you can already do this. Look what you can do running with the Mono framework now and their data providers. Mono has already been up and running on *NIX for years. You can see what they support at: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/  Only SqlServer is built into the framework. It was decided long ago that other technologies would be supported through their respective drivers.

Comment: So it is the first scenario that my question pertains to.  For your second point, I know that you can run ASP.Net MVC with Mono now, but I am concerned about the performance, which looks pretty bad right now. Since MSFT is only open sourcing the CoreCLR, will we see Mono big Mono performance gains in the future? It sounds like the streamlined CoreCLR with Kestrel should be much faster... http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=db

Comment: Microsoft has quietly been investing in Mono for a while now, even back when it was under Novell. By investing I mean throwing actual cash behind it. I think the performance is going to get much better especially with the new direction the company is moving in where all platforms are possible.